# How to round up all numbers during update on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model `Time`which has a column `seconds`. Column type is an integer. So Im wondering what is the right syntax if I want to update all records of `seconds` by rounding up each record of `seconds` to the nearest 100 via the rails console.
I have tried:

```
a = Time.all
a.update_all(seconds: (:seconds).round(-2))
```

Please I would really love to know to correct syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. Can be easily done in console

```
a = Time.all
a.each do |b|
  b.seconds = b.seconds.round(-2)
  b.save
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much @DroidNoob. Exactly what I was looking for!!